# optimize jquery code, sending multiple arrays and simple vars via $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I generate this js at the server side so the arrays could have more elements

```
var o = 'hi world';
var keys = ['foo','bar'];
var values = ['foox', 'barzs'];
```

---

**how can I optimize this part?:**

```
var data = [{name:'prop', value: o}];
data.push({name: 'keys', value: 'foo'});
data.push({name: 'keys', value: 'bar'});
data.push({name: 'values', value: 'foox'});
data.push({name: 'values', value: 'barzs'});

$.post('url', $.param(data), ...);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if with a limited example you're really optimizing anything, but if you actually have large data sets, you could push the values via a loop...

again it depends on what you mean by optimize, but I'm assuming you are dealing with much larger data sets than your example, meaning having to write push statements every single value.

```
var data = [{name:'prop', value: o}];

for ( i in keys ) {
    data.push({ name: 'keys', value: keys[i] });
}

for ( i in values ) {
    data.push({ name: 'values', value: values[i] });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this would be equivalent:

```
$.post('url', {
  'prop': o,
  'keys': ['foo', 'bar'],
  'values': ['foox', 'barzs']
}, function() { ... });
```

To an extent it depends on what your server expects.  Some server environments understand the HTTP convention of treating multiple instances of the same parameter as being an array-valued parameter, while others prefer parameter names to have explicit intrinsic "indexes" like "keys[0]", "keys[1]", etc.  Some understand either.

Comment: mine is asp.net mvc and this way will get keys[0] = 'foo,bar', not the same

Comment: @Omu Well if that's what's happening it's because asp.net would be re-combining the separate parameters on the server. To me, that's an awful idea, but then there are a lot of reasons I don't use ASP :-) If you use TamperData or something like that, you should be able to see that jQuery splits up array-valued parameters so that they really are separate in the HTTP request.